# SF - I am looking for a Sci-Fi book that ends with a forlorn alien on earth who cannot escape

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The male alien has been building or hiding a spaceship. But he is discovered. He disguises himself. And in the end, after accepting that he cannot escape, he sits and removes his eyelashes or maybe his eyelids which were part of his disguise.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154763/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: And this is a full-length novel, not a short story? Can you add any more details to your description? Why was the alien on earth? Was he a spy scouting for an invasion? How long ago did you read it?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218156/audio-book-novel-about-a-human-like-alien-who-comes-to-earth-and-loves-gin (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a bit like [The Man Who Fell to Earth](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2915) by Walter Tevis.

Many of us will be familiar with the film adaptation starring David Bowie and remember the scene where Bowie/Newton is trying to remove his eye shields but is shaking too badly to do it. That scene exists in the book as well:

> When he brought his hand, carrying the tweezer, toward his eyes, the fingers began to tremble uncontrollably. He drew the hand back quickly. He tried again, but could not get the thing near his eye. His hand shook violently this time. “I’m sorry,” he said. “Just a minute more…”